# How to correctly morph shapes with android.graphics.Path?

Tags: android, canvas

For example I have a square shape drawn on `Canvas` with `android.graphics.Path`, how to morph it into circle or any other shape?

It's possible to do it with `SVG`, `VectorDrawables`, you can see examples [here](https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath).

But how to do it with `android.graphics.Path`?

Answer (score 1):

You can morph `vectors` with `AnimtedVectorDrawables`, [here is a tutorial](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html) for that.

One web tools to use is ***[ShapeShifter](https://shapeshifter.design/)***, and [here is a tutorial for that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P35hQOsW0xU).

> **Be aware** that Android don't fully support SVG. 
>   Had issues with gradients since it's done different in SVG then in `VectorDrawables`.

Comment: I need to morph android.graphics.Path that I've drawn with canvas.drawPath, I'm not sure how to convert that into pathData. I'm not using svg or drawables.